# Can wifi admin see viber messages

Tags: wireless-networking, security, privacy, viber

Can a wifi admin can see viber messages?

And how far or detailed can a wifi admin see, like pictures sent through viber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the answer was **yes.**

it could be achieved using special plugin :

from [wireshark forum](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/17291/help-recording-voip-calls)

```
Capture setup is possibly not ready for wifi/wlan capturing. Please read the wiki about capturing traffic in such an environment: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

    I am NOT able to detect the VoIP call being made on these smartphones (using the smartphone app Viber).

well, even if see the wifi/wlan traffic of the phones, you may not be able to capture 'voip' calls made via viber.com. I don't know for sure, but I'm pretty confident, that they will use their own protocol and I hope they will use encryption, otherwise I would consider viber.com a security failure and not a service ;-). Unfortunately both issues (own protocol and encryption) will make it hard/impossible to extract any valuable information from the captured packets. Anyway, you will see how far you get, as soon as your wlan/wifi capture setup works.

HINT: wifi monitoring mode (see wiki) is not supported on Windows with WinPcap, so if you want to capture the wifi/wlan traffic of your android phones you either have to use a special adapter on Windows (AirPcap) or use Linux as the platform for Wireshark.

UPDATE
Please read the following paper regarding viber security. It explains some concepts (protocol,'encryption/scrambling', etc.)

    https://www.os3.nl/2011-2012/students/jeffrey_bosma/courses/ssn/assignments/project
```

Apart from that there were many spy plugins available to detect [it](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2010/10/wireshark-quick-tip-finding-facebook-users-by-chris-greer.html) ,Apart from above have a look over here[detailed tutorial how system adminstrator will spy over u](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/inspiration/8-wireshark-filters-every-wiretapper-uses-spy-web-conversations-and-surfing-habits-0134508/)

Comment: Thank you. I will read through the topics and links that you sent me. Big help!

Comment: The OP was referring to message **not** VoIP calls. In any case it is unlikely a local system admin can record VoIP calls (unless they are inside the network of a VoIP provider). VoIP providers do not (normally) record VoIP calls, but in many countries are obliged to to so when requested to by the appropriate authorities.

Answer (score 5):

#### Can a wifi admin can see viber messages?

A network administrator will be (probably) be able to see there is traffic to Viber.

---

#### Are my messages secure?

Yes, but.

- Viber messages are supposed to be encrypted. However, there have been a number of bugs in the past, for example see [Viber begins fixing image-encryption vulnerability](http://www.cnet.com/news/viber-begins-fixing-image-encryption-vulnerability/). There may still be (undiscovered) bugs in the encryption.
- In addition, your messages are only as secure as your device. If you lose your phone/laptop or someone hacks your PC all bets are off.
- I would not use a messaging app to transfer private/confidential information (for example embarassing photos, your banking details, etc).

> Sending your messages online means trusting the application you send them through and it's important you know exactly what kind of security measures are taken to keep your information private. With Viber, your messages are secure.
>
> All text messages sent through Viber on its supported platforms are encrypted. Media messages, such as photos and videos, are encrypted on Viber for iOS, Viber for Android, Viber for Windows 8 and Viber for Windows Phone 8.
>
> **What does "encrypted" mean?**
>
> Encrypted data refers to data that is taken in its original form and converted into code or other data in order to conceal the original content. In other words, data encryption takes your messages and turns it into a bunch of garble that cannot be deciphered.

Source [Are my messages secure?](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1600146-are-my-messages-secure-)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Oh my. I shouldn't trust messaging apps from now on.

Comment: @Feline It's depends on how paranoid you are. I would not use a messaging app to transfer private/confidential information. And of course your messages are only as secure as your device. If you lose your phone all bets are off.

Comment: @Feline - If you are responsible for what SSL certificates the network uses, then you can trust the administrator cannot view your message, if you are not responsible for which certificates will be used then you cannot trust the administrator does not have the capability to snoop on your secure http traffic.

Comment: Hello David, my phone is still with me. But I began suspecting my housemate who is the wifi admin, knows something about me, info that is on my viber messages. Well I guess, he really has access. Thanks and I will be careful from now.

Comment: @Feline I would not use a messaging app to transfer private/confidential information (for example embarassing photos, your banking details, etc).

Comment: Is there any way to detect Viber traffic independent from IP and Ports? (I mean is there any specific header format for example)?